# How to add text file in netbeans project

Tags: java

Please how can I embed text file in my netbeans project and set it on a jeditorpane using event trigger
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a tutorial on how to use JEditorPane by Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html